# HttpWebRequest and Tomcat

Tags: c#, http, session, tomcat

First, sorry for my poor english.
In tomcat each request open a Session on my web application.

So, this session remains opened for 30 minutes.

Can I use a single Session (via C#) to perform my requests?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm correct on interpreting your question.

Generally, sessions are associated with a particular user with an HTTP cookie. So to reuse a session all you need is to send back the cookie Tomcat sent you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how I can do it with C#?